# Hiding edit column for specific rows in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

**Solved**
Without using runat server property

```
  <a href='editvehiclerequest.aspx?id=<%# objCrypto.EnCrypt(Container.KeyValue.ToString())%>' style='display:<%# Eval("VehicleStatus").ToString() != ("Cancel") ? "block" :"none"%>'>Edit</a>
```

I know this can be achieved using eval in visible property.
How to use eval statement in visible property of the edit column.

**What I tried**

```
'<%# Eval("VehicleStatus").ToString() !=( "cancel") ? "true" : "false" %>'


 <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Width="50px" VisibleIndex="0" Caption="">
                        <DataItemTemplate>
                            <a visible=" '<%# Eval("VehicleStatus").ToString() !=( "cancel") ? "true" : "false" %>'" href="editvehiclerequest.aspx?id=<%# objCrypto.EnCrypt(Container.KeyValue.ToString())%>">Edit</a>
                        </DataItemTemplate>
                    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
```

**My code**

```
<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Width="50px" VisibleIndex="0" Caption="">
                    <DataItemTemplate>
                        <a  href="editvehiclerequest.aspx?id=<%# objCrypto.EnCrypt(Container.KeyValue.ToString())%>">Edit</a>
                    </DataItemTemplate>
                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
```

**The column according to which i have to hide edit column**

```
  <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn Caption="Vehicle<br> Status" FieldName="VehicleStatus" >
                <PropertiesComboBox DropDownStyle="DropDown" DataSourceID="VrmsVehicleStatusDataSource"
                    ValueField="VehicleStatus" IncrementalFilteringMode="StartsWith" TextField="VehicleStatus"
                    ValueType="System.String" />
            </dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>
```

Comment: You need to set that expression for the columns `Visible` property.

Comment: Its not helping.. PLs suggest some way

Comment: Hey sorry I was in Meeting so coudn't able to answer you. Check out the answer. I will delete this comment in time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I advise you o use the `Hyperlink` control instead of the `<a>` anchor. But due to some reason you cant then you need to set the Anchor tags `runat=server` property.

So your new anchor tag will be like,

```
<a runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("VehicleStatus").ToString() != ("cancel") ? Convert.ToBoolean("true") : Convert.ToBoolean("false") %>' href="editvehiclerequest.aspx?id=<%# objCrypto.EnCrypt(Container.KeyValue.ToString())%>">Edit</a>
```

This should work. But you should use `HyperLink` control.